# How to ignore a gem per computer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

By some reason some of the developers use a gem and the others don't.

Sometimes I met code like that:

```
if File.exist?('USE_MY_GEM')
  gem 'my_gem'
end
```

and `USE_MY_GEM` written in `.gitignore`. But I believe this is not very good practice.

How to turn a gem off / on for a specific machine?

Comment: Could you install gem in some computers instead of install gem throught Gemfile. If you do this, project will be clean.

Comment: Exactly like they are doing right now, with a conditional statement. Does the gem needs to be un the project's bundle? It could simply be installed on the system using `gem install my_gem` and not be in the bundle.

Comment: Yes, it should be in Gemfile, because most of them uses a gem, but not everyone. So, keeping it in Bundle but ignoring is preferable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution was obvious.

We can manage gems in a way we usually manage groups.

Just wrap gem in a group and add `--without` option:

`Gemfile`

```
group :my_gem do
  gem 'my_gem'
end
```

In console:

```
$ bundle install --without my_gem
```

Ensure that `.gitignore` contains:

```
/.bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [Bundler groups feature](http://bundler.io/groups.html). This way the `Gemfile` might contain the group, containing these superfluous gem[s] some developers use.

From the documentation:

> Restrict the groups of gems that you want to add to the load path. Only gems in these groups will be require'able:
>
> ```
> require 'rubygems'
> require 'bundler'
> Bundler.setup(:default, :ci)
> require 'nokogiri'
> ```